# refresh badges to file icons in Finder

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, applescript, overlay

I done Icon overlay in OS X and I just need to update the overlay icon when it's status changed. I tried many techniques, but it don't works. I don't need to restart the finder, I just want to update the badge icon of specific file.

For this case I tried some ways.

1. Just touch and remove the file, it would trigger the refresh the finder.
2. ```
   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:path inFileViewerRootedAtPath:nil];
   ```

   It works well but it also open the finder window when it is not active.( shall we have any option to do not open the finder window here)

Apart from above two ways, I need any optimised way to refresh the File's badge icon in finder

Comment: have you found any solution of this issue? I am having same issue with Finder Sync Extension

Comment: @jigs I have used following workaround

Answer (score 0):

```
try
  tell application "Finder"
    set a to get the bounds of the front window
    set b to get the bounds of the front window
    set bound to (item 3 of a) + 1
    set item 3 of a to bound
    set bounds of the front window to a
    set bounds of the front window to b
  end tell
  return a
on error msg number num
--display dialog "Unable to launch " & msg & " (" & (num as text) & ")"return msg
    return msg
end try
```

Comment: thanks for post answer but its won't work for me..:( Can you please elaborate that script you posted?

Comment: It's just resize the finder window, which is trigger the finder to update its' file, so the icons are updated.

Comment: Yes you are right, its resize the finder window, but won't refresh the finder.

Comment: No, it's refreshing, have you properly load the finder sync extension?

Comment: Yes, its already enabled. Can you please let me know while fire the above script then any finder delegate method or any other method which will execute at that time for refreshing the badge?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.